# Google Sheets: same values don't recognized as same

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, string-formatting, google-sheets-formula, number-formatting

I'm trying to build an IF formula, where I compare two dates, but my formula means same dates would be different.

So, I have in A2 a date, like `2019-11-04`.

In B2 I have a date like `201945`.

In A3 I check the week number with `=isoweeknum(A2)` and get 45.

In B3 I check the week number with `=MID(B2; 5; 2)` and get 45 too.

Then i try to compare them with `=IF(((isoweeknum(A2))=(MID(B2;5;2))); "OK"; "different numbers")` - but get `different numbers`.

On trying to write the formula as `=IF(a3=b3; "OK"; "different numbers")` I get `different numbers` too.

Why Sheets treat it as different? How should I write the formula so, that these same values are recognized as same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MID` auto-converts stuff to string (Plain text) so try:

```
=IF(ISOWEEKNUM(A2)=MID(B2; 5; 2)*1; "OK"; "different numbers")
```

[image: 0]